# Can't refer to EVP_DigestSign and EVP_DigestVerify when make check OSSLEDDSATests of Softhsmv2

Tags: reference, openssl, undefined, cppunit, softhsm

I'm trying to update my installation with openssl 1.1.1j and SoftHSMv2 v2.6.1, command "make" is passed, but "make check" is failed. can't refer to EVP_DigestSign and EVP_DigestVerify in OSSLEDDSA.cpp. the logs is :

```
Making check in src
make[1]: 进入目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src”
Making check in lib
make[2]: 进入目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib”
Making check in common
make[3]: 进入目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/common”
make[3]: 对“check”无需做任何事。
make[3]: 离开目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/common”
Making check in crypto
make[3]: 进入目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/crypto”
Making check in test
make[4]: 进入目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/crypto/test”
make cryptotest
make[5]: 进入目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/crypto/test”
/bin/sh ../../../../libtool --tag=CXX --mode=link g++ -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fvisibility=hidden -lcrypto -L/usr/local/lib -lcppunit -ldl -no-install -o cryptotest cryptotest.o AESTests.o DESTests.o DHTests.o DSATests.o ECDHTests.o ECDSATests.o EDDSATests.o GOSTTests.o HashTests.o MacTests.o RNGTests.o RSATests.o chisq.o ent.o iso8859.o randtest.o ../../libsofthsm_convarch.la -ldl
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -Wall -Wextra -fvisibility=hidden -o cryptotest cryptotest.o AESTests.o DESTests.o DHTests.o DSATests.o ECDHTests.o ECDSATests.o EDDSATests.o GOSTTests.o HashTests.o MacTests.o RNGTests.o RSATests.o chisq.o ent.o iso8859.o randtest.o -L/usr/local/lib /usr/local/lib/libcppunit.so ../../.libs/libsofthsm_convarch.a -lcrypto /usr/lib/../lib64/libstdc++.so -lm -ldl -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/../lib64 -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/../lib64
../../.libs/libsofthsm_convarch.a(OSSLEDDSA.o): In function OSSLEDDSA::sign(PrivateKey*, ByteString const&, ByteString&, AsymMech::Type, void const*, unsigned long)': /home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/crypto/OSSLEDDSA.cpp:94: undefined reference to EVP_DigestSign'
../../.libs/libsofthsm_convarch.a(OSSLEDDSA.o): In function OSSLEDDSA::verify(PublicKey*, ByteString const&, ByteString const&, AsymMech::Type, void const*, unsigned long)': /home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/crypto/OSSLEDDSA.cpp:175: undefined reference to EVP_DigestVerify'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[5]: *** [cryptotest] 错误 1
make[5]: 离开目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/crypto/test”
make[4]: *** [check-am] 错误 2
make[4]: 离开目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/crypto/test”
make[3]: *** [check-recursive] 错误 1
make[3]: 离开目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib/crypto”
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] 错误 1
make[2]: 离开目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src/lib”
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] 错误 1
make[1]: 离开目录“/home/centos/gopath/src/liucy/SoftHSMv2/src”
make: *** [check-recursive] 错误 1
```

I try to delete the OSSLEDDSA from makefile, "make check" is passed.

in addition, based on the same server environment, I write a demo to invoke "EVP_DigestSign" simply , it is also passed.

so, I don't know what wrong is in my environment, need some help, thanks.

Comment: configure logs  : ``` checking for crypto backend... OpenSSL
checking what are the OpenSSL includes...
checking what are the OpenSSL libs...  -lcrypto
checking openssl/ssl.h usability... yes
checking openssl/ssl.h presence... yes
checking for openssl/ssl.h... yes
checking for BN_new in -lcrypto... yes
checking for OpenSSL version... >= 1.0.0
checking for OpenSSL ECC support... Found P256, P384, and P521
checking for OpenSSL EDDSA ED25519 support... Found ED25519
checking for OpenSSL EDDSA ED448 support... Found ED448
checking for OpenSSL GOST support... Cannot find GOST engine```

Answer (score 0):

I have always suspected that it is an environmental problem. because of "make" can be passed, so I feel confused.

Anyway, after telling SoftHSM's configure script where to find the OpenSSL, "make check" is passed.